# zoom in on google map markers

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google Maps API to display an account location and have a function that will then display nearby account locations.  The issue is I'd like to zoom in to show the markers when the getNearbyAccounts function is called.  At the current zoom level you cannot see all the markers. It just looks like a clump of markers all jumbled together.

Here is my page code:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="AccountMapControllerExtension" doctype="html-5.0" >
<apex:sectionHeader title="Account Mapping Tool"/>
<title>Account Map</title>

<head>
    <!-- STYLE SHEETS  -->
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR ($Resource.jQueryUI, '/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.9.0.custom.css')}" />

</head>
<style>    

    .urlLinks {

        color: blue;
        text-decoration:underline

    }


    #map {
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size:12px;
        line-height:normal !important;
        height:400px;        
        padding: 20px;
    }       
    .roundCornerCss{ 
        /* outer shadows  (note the rgba is red, green, blue, alpha) */
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); 
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 6px rgba(23, 69, 88, .5);

        /* rounded corners */
        -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
        -moz-border-radius: 7px; 
        border-radius: 7px;

        /* gradients */
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, 
        color-stop(0%, white), color-stop(15%, white), color-stop(100%, #D7E9F5)); 
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, white 0%, white 55%, #D5E4F3 130%); 
    }   

    #loadingScreen {
        background: url({!URLFOR($Resource.Markers, 'Markers/ajax-loader.gif')}) no-repeat 5px 8px;
        padding-left: 50px;
    }

    /* hide the close x on the loading screen */
    .loadingScreenWindow .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
        display: none;
    }

</style>
<body>
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQueryUI, '/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js')}"/>  
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQueryUI, '/js/jquery-1.8.2.js')}"/>
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQueryUI, '/js/jquery-ui-1.9.0.custom.js')}"/>      
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

// Global Variables

var geocoder;
var map;
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var places = [];
var title_content = new Array();                    
var popup_content = new Array();                    
var address = new Array();
var address_position = 0;                    
var timeout = 600;
var pendingCalls = {};  

var markersArray = [];

$j = $.noConflict(); // No Conflict Custom $j


// Initialize

$j(document).ready(function(){
    var acctId = document.getElementById("hdnAccountId").value;
    if(acctId == "") {
        $j("#inputDiv").css("display","none");
    }
    regDialogs();

});

// Load Google Map

function initialize() {

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();   
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(42.3583, -71.0603); // Boston, MA as Center
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 3,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    } 
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
}

function regDialogs(){

    $j( "#pendDiv" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        title: 'Pending Call Reports'
    });

    $j("#loadingScreen").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,    // set this to false so we can manually open it
        dialogClass: "loadingScreenWindow",
        closeOnEscape: false,
        draggable: false,
        width: 460,
        minHeight: 50,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {},
        resizable: false,
        open: function() {
            // scrollbar fix for IE
            $j('body').css('overflow','hidden');
        },
        close: function() {
            // reset overflow
            $j('body').css('overflow','auto');
        }
    }); // end of dialog    
}

// Waiting Dialog on Loading
function waitingDialog() {

    $j("#loadingScreen").html('<p>Please Wait ...</p>');
    $j("#loadingScreen").dialog('option', 'title', 'Loading');
    $j("#loadingScreen").dialog('open');

}
// Close Waiting Dialog
function closeWaitingDialog() {
    $j("#loadingScreen").dialog('close');

}

function getCurrentAccountMap() {
    var billingStreet = '{!account.BillingStreet}';
    var billingCity = '{!account.BillingCity}';
    var billingState = '{!account.BillingState}';
    var billingCountry = '{!account.BillingCountry}';
    var billingPostalCode = '{!account.BillingPostalCode}';
    address_position = 0;

    $j("#messages").empty();

    clearOverlay(); // Remove existing markers if any

    var addr = billingStreet + ',' + billingCity + ',' + 
                billingState + ',' + billingCountry + ',' + 
                billingPostalCode; 

   address.push(addr);      
   addMarker(address_position);
}

function getAccountsNearbyMap(){

    waitingDialog(); // Start Loading
    var lat = '{!account.Geolocation__Latitude__s}';
    var lng = '{!account.Geolocation__Longitude__s}';   
    var distance = '';
    lat = parseFloat(lat);
    lng = parseFloat(lng);

    if($j("select option:selected").text() == 'within 10 miles'){
        distance = $j("select option:selected").val()
    }
    if($j("select option:selected").text() == 'within 25 miles'){
        distance = $j("select option:selected").val()
    }
    if($j("select option:selected").text() == 'within 50 miles'){
        distance = $j("select option:selected").val()
    }
    if($j("select option:selected").text() == 'within 100 miles'){
        distance = $j("select option:selected").val()
    }
    if($j("select option:selected").text() == 'within 250 miles'){
        distance = $j("select option:selected").val()
    }
    if($j("select option:selected").text() == 'within 500 miles'){
        distance = $j("select option:selected").val()
    }

    AccountMapControllerExtension.getNearbyAccounts(lat,lng,distance,function(result,event){

        $j("#messages").empty();

        clearOverlay(); // Remove existing markers if any

        if(event.type == 'exception'){
                alert('Error ' + event.message);
        }else {

            address = new Array();
            address_position = 0;
            var completeDate = '';
            var pendClick = '';
            var hasCallRecords = false;

            $j.each(result,function(rec){
                var addr = result[rec].BillingStreet  + ',' + result[rec].BillingCity    + ',' + 
                                   result[rec].BillingState   + ',' + result[rec].BillingCountry + ',' + 
                                   result[rec].BillingPostalCode; 
                address.push(addr); 
            });

            if(address.length > 1){
                addMarker(address_position);
            }else{
                addMarker(address_position);
                $j("#messages").append('<h3 style="color:red;">There are no nearby accounts found within the range specified</h3><br/>');
                closeWaitingDialog();
                return false;

            }
        }

    });

  }

  function addMarker(position){
        geocoder.geocode({'address': address[position]}, function(results, status){
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                places[position] = results[0].geometry.location;                                    
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: places[position],
                    title:title_content[position],
                    icon: getMapIconUrl(position),
                    map: map
                });
                map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
                map.setZoom(map.getZoom()+2);
                markersArray.push(marker);
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    if (!infowindow) {
                        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({maxWidth: 200});
                    }
                    infowindow.setContent(popup_content[position]);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                });


            }
            else{
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT){
                    setTimeout(function() { addMarker(position); }, (timeout * 3));
                }
            }
            address_position++;
            if (address_position < address.length){
                setTimeout(function() { addMarker(address_position); }, (timeout));
            }
            closeWaitingDialog();

        });
    }

    function clearOverlay(){

        for (var i = 0; i < markersArray.length; i++ ) {
            markersArray[i].setMap(null);
        }

    }

    /*
       Sets the Marker Type/Color
    */

    function getMapIconUrl(markerNumber){

        var mapIconUrl = "{!URLFOR($Resource.Markers, 'Markers/PinkPin.png')}";

        return mapIconUrl;
    }
    window.onload = function() {
        getCurrentAccountMap();
    };
</script>
<!-- HTML Content -->
<input type="hidden" value="{!account.Id}" id="hdnAccountId" />
<div id="inputDiv">
Search Nearby Accounts
<select id="selectOption">
    <option value="10">within 10 miles</option>
    <option value="25">within 25 miles</option>
    <option value="50">within 50 miles</option>
    <option value="100">within 100 miles</option>
    <option value="250">within 250 miles</option>
    <option value="500">within 500 miles</option>
</select><br/>
<div id="rangeDiv"></div><br/>
<input type="button" onclick="getAccountsNearbyMap();" class="btn" value="Get Accounts Nearby"/>
</div><br/><br/>

<div id="messages"></div><br/>

<div id="map" class="roundCornerCss"></div>

<script>
     initialize();
</script>

<div id="canvas_div"></div>
<div id="pendDiv"></div>        
<div id="loadingScreen"></div>  
</body>
</apex:page>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Zoom to fit all the markers?  Zoom to fit some to be defined subset of the markers?  What have you tried?  Have you seen the [fitBounds method in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map)?

Answer (score 0):

Are you just looking to increase the zoom level. This can be done by set zoom

```
map.setZoom(map.getZoom()+2)
```

Comment: I tried `map.setZoom(map.getZoom()+2)` but it is zooming in on the default lat/lng coordinates and not where the markers are located.  By default, it is set to Boston, MA, but, the marker locations is in a different location so I need it to zoom in at the marker location.

Comment: oh. how many markers are there? If there's one marker u can use map.setCenter(marker.getPosition())

Comment: I added `map.setCenter(marker.getPosition())` and `map.setZoom(map.getZoom()+2)`. See my updated code in my original post.  It is zooming in and positioning correctly, but every time I click the button to find nearby accounts, it zooms in again, and again, and again, etc.  Initially, when I hit the page, it will show one marker location for an account, which I'd like to position the map on, then when I click get nearby accounts, I'd like to zoom in enough so none of the markers are jumbled up on top of each other.

Comment: u need to use fitbounds. Figure the maps bounds out(or get the common area of markers) and use fit bounds

Answer (score 0):

2 options:

1. In your "addMarker" function, add the position of the marker to a [google.maps.LatLngBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds) object (with .extend), then once all the markers have been placed on the map, do a [map.fitBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) on the resulting bounds
2. Create a [google.maps.Circle](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Circle) with the search radius centered on the search location (display it if you want), then get its bounds and do a map.fitBounds on it.